# scrjura link does not become converted to html using tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, scrjura

This is a question for tex4ht experts.

I'm writing contracts in German language. MWE:

```
\documentclass[pagesize, ngerman, fontsize=12pt, parskip=half, ref=nosentence]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel, scrjura, xspace}


  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = * }

\begin{document}
\begin{contract}
  \Clause{title=First of seven}
\label{CLA:first}

This is some text.

Some more text.\label{PAR:second-par}

And.

\Clause{title=Second of seven}
\label{CLA:second}

We refer to \ref{CLA:first}.

We refer to \ref{PAR:second-par}.

We refer to \refPar{PAR:second-par}.

We refer to \refParN[arabic]{PAR:second-par}.%%% <= Issue !

\end{contract}
\end{document}
```

The scrjura package comes with a lot of commands to refer to different places of a contract. Some don't work with tex4ht.

If you convert this example file to html using this command:

```
htlatex example.tex "scrjura" " -cunihtf"
```

the command `\refParN[arabic]{PAR:second-par}` will not be converted. The link is simply missing.

scrjura is the name of a config file a *very* helpful [soul](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2891/michal-h21) once wrote for me. This is the code of scrjura.cfg (for test cases just store in the same folder where example.tex resides):

```
\catcode`\:=11
\makeatletter

\Preamble{html,charset=utf-8}

\begin{document} 

\def\qtchr{\expandafter\@gobble\string\"}
\
\ConfigureList{contract}
  {\HCode{<div class=\qtchr contract\qtchr>}}
  {\HCode{</div>}}
  {}{}

\append:def\contract@paragraph@font{\a:contract@paragraph@font} 
\append:def\contract@paragraph@font{\b:contract@paragraph@font} 

\NewConfigure{contract@paragraph@font}{2}
\Configure{contract@paragraph@font}
  {\HCode{<div class=\qtchr paragraph\qtchr>}}
  {\Tg</div>}

 \pend:def\parformat{\a:parformat} 
 \append:def\parformat{\b:parformat} 

 \NewConfigure{parformat}{2}
 \Configure{parformat}
   {\EndP\HCode{<p class=\qtchr para\qtchr>
    <span class=\qtchr sentence\qtchr>}}
   {\Tg</span>}

 \Css{.sentence{margin-left:2em; padding-top: .5em;}}
 \Css{.paragraph{margin: 1em;}}
 \Css{.para{margin: .5em;}}

\EndPreamble 

\catcode`\:=12
\makeatother

\endinput
```

*If anybody knows how to amend scrjura.cfg to get such links like `\refPar` converted, I'd be very thankful.*

By the way, scrjura.sty years ago used `\Paragraph{title=First of seven}` instead now `\Clause{title=...}`.

Comment: the issue is that Scjura expects cross-references to be in specific format, but `tex4ht` redefines them to suits them to its needs, so everything gets messy. I am bit busy now, but will look at this issue at the end of the week.

Comment: I was able to get correct text for `\refParN`, but links don't work. I will keep trying.

Comment: @michal.h21 Who cares, if the link works, as long as `\refPar` and `\refParN` are converted into e.g. »Absatz 5« or »5«. If this worked, I'd be satisfied, really!

Comment: you may care :) I will post answer without functional links later today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a proper `scrjura.4ht` configuration file for `tex4ht`:

```
\def\qtchr{\expandafter\@gobble\string\"}
\ConfigureEnv{contract}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class=\qtchr contract\qtchr>}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\end:prevpara\HCode{</div>}}
{}{}

\pend:def\contract@paragraph@font{\a:contract@paragraph@font} 
\append:def\contract@paragraph@font{\b:contract@paragraph@font\gdef\end:prevpara{}} 

\NewConfigure{contract@paragraph@font}{2}
\Configure{contract@paragraph@font}
  {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\end:prevpara\HCode{<div class=\qtchr paragraph\qtchr>}}
  {\Tg</div>}

% \end:prevpara is needed to correctly handle paragraphs
\def\end:prevpara{}
\pend:def\parformat{\end:prevpara\a:parformat} 
\append:def\parformat{\b:parformat\global\let\end:prevpara\c:parformat} 

\NewConfigure{parformat}{3}
\Configure{parformat}
{\EndP\HCode{<p class=\qtchr para\qtchr>\Hnewline
<span class=\qtchr sentence\qtchr>}}
    {\Tg</span>}{\Tg</p>}


% this is a modified version of original macro from scrjura.sty
\renewcommand*{\ref@Par}[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname r@#2\endcsname\relax
    \ref#1{#2}%
  \else
    \begingroup
      % this definitions are needed to get correct content from the \csname r@#2\endcsname
      \def\rEfLiNK##1##2{##2}
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@tempb
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble\csname r@#2\endcsname}%
      \def\@tempc##1##2\@nil{##1}%
      \let\scrjura@separator\@gobble
      \protected@edef\@tempa{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@tempc
        \csname r@#2\endcsname\noexpand\@nil}%
      \def\@tempc##1##2##3\@nil{##2}%
      \protected@edef\@tempa{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@tempc
        \@tempa{%
          \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
          \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
          \@latex@warning{Reference `#2' on page \thepage \space
            with undefined par number}%
        }\noexpand\@nil}%
      \let\@@protect\protect
      \let\protect\noexpand
      \expandafter\edef\csname r@#2\endcsname{{\@tempa}\@tempb}%
      \let\protect\@@protect
      \ref#1{#2}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
 \Css{.sentence{margin-left:2em; padding-top: .5em;}}
 \Css{.paragraph{margin: 1em;}}
 \Css{.para{margin: .5em;}}
```

The issue with `\refPar` and `\refParN` macros is that they rely on a specific structure of cross-references, which is different with `tex4ht`. I've patched the cross-reference handling macro `\ref@Par` to be somehow compatible. The only issue is that links for these commands don't work, but at least the text seems to be good:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm on a business trip and had no time to look into this christmas present. I saved the code as "scrjura.4ht" in the folder were my texfile resides. With the command `htlatex filename.tex "scrjura.4ht" " -cunihtf"` I'm getting an error: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \ConfigureEnv
                 {contract}` What am I doing the wrong way?

Comment: Ah: Is this unreasonable? It works: `htlatex filename.tex "scrjura" "scrjura.4ht, -cunihtf" `

Comment: @KeksDose the `scrjura.4ht` file is loaded automatically, you can just use `make4ht filename.tex`. (`htlatex` is deprecated, use `make4ht` instead)

Comment: OK, so easy.... So much to learn...